# What is the integral of $x^{-2\theta}$?

Tags: integration

> What is the integral of $x^{-2\theta}$?

Not sure how the integration works with two variables. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: Depends, what do you want this integral for? What was the original question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to choose a variable to integrate, the other remains as a constant. Or do both, one at a time.

Integrating with respect to x:
\begin{align*}
\int x^{-2 \theta} dx &= \frac{x^{1 - 2\theta}}{1 - 2\theta} + C\\
\end{align*}
Integrating with respect to  θ:
\begin{align*}
\int x^{-2 \theta} d \theta &= -\frac{x^{-2 \theta}}{2 \ln(x)} + C
\end{align*}